# Is it possible to add constraints and costs to prog with multi-thread?

Tags: drake

We are following some papers[1] to construct a whole-body controller using Drake. Currently, with a 34-Dof humanoid model, the formulation and solve time is about 4ms and 3ms in `python`, still far from our purpose of 0.5~1.0 kHz.

We notice that `AddLinearEqualityConstraint`, `AddLinearEqualityConstraint`, `AddCost`, etc, will take several hundred microseconds each time adding a constraint or cost. This part of time consumption accounts for a considerable part of 4ms formulation time, and we want to optimize this part of time consumption first.

we wonder is it possible to add constraints and costs with multi-thread, to speed up the prog formulation?

[1] Kuindersma, S., Permenter, F. and Tedrake, R., 2014, May. An efficiently solvable quadratic program for stabilizing dynamic locomotion. In 2014 IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation (ICRA) (pp. 2589-2594). IEEE.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to add constraints/costs in multiple threads. In MathematicalProgram, the linear constraints are stored inside MathematicalProgram as `std::vector<Binding<LinearConstraint>>`, and each time calling AddLinearConstraint, it pushes back a new constraint into this vector. std::vector is not thread safe and it would incur data race if you do so.

One idea to improve the computation time is to avoid using symbolic expression when you add constraints/costs, but instead add them through matrix/vectors. For example, instead of doing

```cc
prog.AddLinearConstraint(x[0] + 2 * x[1] == 2)
```

using the symbolic expression, you can do

```cc
prog.AddLinearEqualityConstraint(Eigen::RowVector2d(1, 2), Vector1d(2), x);
```

If you really want to achieve best performance, I would suggest to directly use the solver's API instead of through Drake's MathematicalProgram. For example if you use Gurobi, then construct your optimization program using Gurobi's API directly. This would avoid the overhead of Drake constructing a MathematicalProgram and then convert it to Gurobi's format.

Comment: Another tip: If you want to want to repeated solve similar optimization problems, then you probably do not want to use `AddConstraint` on each iteration, but rather make the `MathematicalProgram` once, and the use the `Update*` methods of the constraint class and resolve.

Comment: yes, we are passing coefficient matrix directly to drake now, like `prog.AddLinearConstraint(A, lb, ub, vars)` .  But I guess what you said means that with a thread-safe way to read/write std::vector, it is possible to add constraints/costs in multiple threads ~ For example, initialize the vector size and use fix read-write index.

Comment: @RussTedrake thanks, prof. In most constraints, the jacobian matrix,  MassMatrix, etc, changed every time solving the problem. So the constraints need to be removed and re-add if make the prog only once, and removing constraints also takes time.

Comment: `For example, initialize the vector size and use fix read-write index`

We currently don't support this yet. The only way to modify the constraint is through AddConstraint which pushes the constraint into the vector. But you can modify Drake's MathematicalProgram code to modify the vector with index.

Comment: thanks very much, will do more investigate first